# How to change the style in a list of figures to change the space after the numbering point?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I am working on my thesis and I have some issues with the style and format in the list of figures and list of tables. Now I am using the command \listoftables but the resulting format is not adequate. I have almost 100 figures so for example:

B.7. xxxxx
But when I reach the Figure B.11  spacing after point is lost like this:

B.11.xxxx

I'm new to using latex so I don't know how to change or add this space. I only use the command \listofigures but I don't know how to change the style or add this space that I need.

Thanks for your help! :D

[image: List of figures]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it directly in Latex. There are more comfortable packages available at ctan, see e.g. package `tocloft` at https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf . `1em` is roughly the width of letter m; you can also use common units like `1mm`, `1in` or `1cm`.

Catcodes where introduced in TeX to e.g. tell a letter from a control sequence in a stream of bytes. See e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode for details.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\makeatletter% internal: changing catcode of @ to 11 = "letter"
  % indenting list of tables
  \renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{12.3em}{5.5em}}
\makeatother% internal: changing catcode of @ to 12 = "other sign"

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables

\chapter{Something to start with}
    \begin{table}
      xyz \\
      \caption{A dummy table}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
      xyz \\
      \caption{An other dummy table}
    \end{table}

\chapter{Something else}
    \begin{table}
      xyz \\
     \caption{Just an other dummy table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tocloft` package is designed for this.

```
% lofspaceprob.tex  SE 651098

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em} % increase space for figure numbers
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  ILLUSTRATION
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And similarly change `\cfttabnumwidth` for table number in the LoT.

[image: screenshot]